# Why Live Speech to Text with Watson Speech to Text return Handshake status 403 Forbidden?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I read this tutorial [Live speech to text with watson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCyuZM454_I&t=1046s&ab_channel=NicholasRenotte) and it return `Handshake status 403 Forbidden`

I really followed the tutorial to the letter,

I dont know what is missing, can someone help me?
I use windows

transcribe.py : [transcribe.py](https://github.com/IBM/watson-streaming-stt/blob/master/transcribe.py)

```
REGION_MAP = {
    'us-east': 'gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net',
    'us-south': 'stream.watsonplatform.net',
    'eu-gb': 'stream.watsonplatform.net',
    'eu-de': 'stream-fra.watsonplatform.net',
    'au-syd': 'gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net',
    'jp-tok': 'gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net',
}
#................................................
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to get started here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @data_henrik I edit this :)